# List<Interface1 & Interface 2> without empty interface Interface3:Interface1,Interface2?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm building a UI panel. You can add things to display on it, and it stores them in a list.

The things added to it need to inherit from IAddable, as that allows them to be added to the camera (facilitates the cascade of game loop updates, rendering etc). They also need to be IRectangular, which exposes size and positions, so that the panel can sort & position them.

I currently have an interface:

```
public interface IRectangularAddable : IAddable, IRectangular { }
```

so then my Panel can only have IRectangularAddables added to it, and holds a List of IRectangularAddables which drive both sets of functionality.

It feels like a code smell to have an Interface which simply inherits from two others without adding members, is this against [CA1040](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1040)?

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: So currently your `IRectangularAddable` would only work as a baseline marker.

Comment: that is the way to go because there is no multiple inheritance in C#.... so this can only achieved through interfaces exactly like what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Creating interfaces as above is not against [CA1040](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1040?view=vs-2019), because you implement 2 or more interfaces.

**Long answer**

Also, when you actually read the rule, the first section "Cause", states that:

*Cause:*
*The interface does not declare any members or implement two or more other interfaces.*

That means, making an interface that does not declare members and implements only one other interface would violate CA1040, while implementing two interfaces will not.

Also, when you let the code be inspected, that rule should actually not trigger in your case.